# Using "trade-off" in a right way

Tags: grammaticality

I'm writing a paper and would like to know whether my quoted sentence is right or not.

To add more information, I have an improved algorithm which needs a threshold size. If we set that threshold size to a low value, algorithm 1 plays leading role, and if we set it to a high value then algorithm 2 plays leading role.

> From what was said, it is clear that it could be argued that what is the best threshold because of trade-off between using algorithm 1 and algorithm 2.

Comment: Although I've improved the question (I think!) this is still proof-reading or ghost-writing, which is off-topic. It might be possible to rescue the question and make it on-topic, perhaps asking about usage of *trade-off* generically (so I won't vote to close yet), but that will probably end up being General Reference.

Comment: That's not an actual sentence.

Comment: Off topic (writing advice/critique).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade-off)

> A trade-off (or tradeoff) is a situation that involves losing one
>   quality or aspect of something in return for gaining another quality
>   or aspect. It often implies a decision to be made with full
>   comprehension of both the upside and downside of a particular choice;
>   the term is also used in an evolutionary context, in which case the
>   selection process acts as the "decision-maker".

So is this the case with your algorithms?

Also if it is clear, then there is no need to argue

Here is what I would find a better use of trade-off

> From what was said, it can be argued which is the best threshold due to the trade-off between the slowness of algorithm 1 and the higher cpu-usage of algorithm 2.

Comment: Yup. Trade-offs exist *between* alternatives.